# Custom Panel does not render correctly in XAML Designer

Tags: wpf, xaml, designer

I have made a custom panel containing an Expander, which has a Stackpanel where it sorts in it's direct children, instead of having it in the Panel's Children. However, the designer refuses to render any of the direct child's (the Expander) children.

Is there something else that needs to be done, to invalidate the layout for the designer to notice that there are something in there?

```
public class ExpanderPanel : Panel
{
    const double leftMargin = 24.0;

    private Expander _expander;

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(ExpanderPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, (d, e) =>
        {
            var panel = d as ExpanderPanel;
            panel._expander.Header = panel.Header;
        }));

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExpandedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsExpanded", typeof(bool), typeof(ExpanderPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, (d, e) =>
        {
            var panel = d as ExpanderPanel;
            panel._expander.IsExpanded = panel.IsExpanded;
        }));

    public ExpanderPanel()
    {
        _expander = new Expander()
        {
            Content = new StackPanel()
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin - 2, 0, 0, 0) // The Margin - 2 for borders... Don't know a better way...
            },
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        };

        Children.Add(_expander);
    }

    private void InitializePanel()
    {
        _expander.Header = Header;
        _expander.Width = Width;
        _expander.IsExpanded = IsExpanded;

        var sp = _expander.Content as StackPanel;

        while (InternalChildren.Count > 1)
        {
            var child = InternalChildren[1];
            InternalChildren.RemoveAt(1);
            sp.Children.Add(child);
        }
    }

    public override void EndInit()
    {
        base.EndInit();
        InitializePanel();
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var size = new Size();

        _expander.Width = availableSize.Width;

        _expander.Measure(availableSize);
        size.Width = leftMargin + _expander.DesiredSize.Width;
        if (size.Width > availableSize.Width)
        {
            size.Width = availableSize.Width;
        }

        size.Height += _expander.DesiredSize.Height;

        return size;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var location = new Point();

        _expander.Arrange(new Rect(location, _expander.DesiredSize));

        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer myself by logging from the class: The constructor is never called when run through the designer. Therefore the Expander is not created, and I'd assume some NullReferenceExceptions occur.

What I do not understand is why the constructor does not get called. Fixed by putting the logic in the constructor in the Initialize method which is called by a event handler.